# Ignoring fermions in string theory/supergravity

Tags: supersymmetry, fermions

Often in string theory/supergravity, papers will say something along the lines of "we set all the fermions to zero and focus purely on the bosonic field content". See e.g. the final lines on p3 of [hep-th/0605203](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0605203):

> To place the results in physical context, let us recall the general
>   strategy of finding vacua in heterotic string theory with spacetime
>   supersymmetry. Instead of solving the full fledged string equations of
>   motion, which include all massive modes, one finds a supersymmetric
>   configuration in the field theory approximation. In particular, one
>   solves for a bosonic configuration in which all fermions can be
>   consistently set to zero.

I have two questions:

1. Why would you do this? I guess the answer is probably to simplify calculations.
2. More importantly, why is this allowed? They all say that it is consistent to truncate these fields. But why?

Comment: Do you have a ref?

Comment: @innisfree see the last line of p3 in e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0605203

Comment: The paper you are referring to looks for background configurations (if you are referring to eq 1.9 - 1.11). In that case, you set all fermionic fields to zero because it is not possible to give them a VEV and preserve the Lorentz invariance at the same time. Then, you solve the Killing Spinor equation to determine what are the possible background configurations.

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't this the same as asking why you minimise only the scalar potential in ordinary QFT? In QFT non-scalar tadpoles always vanish by Lorentz invariance, I guess something similar happens in ST?! Or is this a red herring?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Depends on the context. Normally, people use bosonic truncation of supersymmetric actions because supersymmetry fixes relative coefficients in a Lagrangian for a given model.
2. It is not "allowed". It is never consistent to truncate all the fermionic fields. Supersymmetry means you have equal number of bosons and fermions. Once you truncate "all" fermions, then you have to truncate "all" bosons as well. However, there are cases where you can truncate some of the bosonic and fermionic fields together. Usually, these fermionic and bosonic fields form a "multiplet" and usually you can truncate a multiplet from your theory depending on what you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found a reference that better represents my question. Perhaps you already answered it and it's just not clear to me yet. Hopefully you can clarify further:

On p631 of the book below, they talk about having only non-zero bosons (see under 12.26). This would seem inconsistent with SUSY according to your above post? 

 https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qZXwCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA629&lpg=PA629&dq=%22minimal+spinor%22&source=bl&ots=9lYtk3HyQr&sig=NsR6OFhllUA9L5P8G0F_k9WyJiA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJqceokevLAhXFVhQKHUVDC3QQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22minimal%20spinor%22&f=false

Comment: Yes, it is consistent. The number of bosons should be equal to the number of fermions. In that case, you set all fermionic degrees of freedom to zero, and give a vev to all bosons. so, no degree of freedom remain. All fermions can be set to zero by giving appropriate vev to bosons except the gravitino. The gravitino transformation has a derivative in the SUSY transformation parameter because gravitino is the field that gauges the supersymmetry. In order to see what are the possible background configurations, you then have to solve that diff. equation $\delta \Psi_\mu = D_\mu \epsilon = 0$.

Comment: Thanks that helps. But...(i) if we leave gravitino switched on, there must be a corresponding boson left on as well? (ii) essentially giving a vev means it resides at a stationary point of the action (solution of equations of motion) and therefore has no freedom to change, right?

Comment: (1). Yes, if the gravitino is switched on, then some of the bosonic degrees of freedom survives. For instance, in 4D N=1  graviton survives if you keep gravitno, and in 4D N=2, if gravitino is on, then graviton as well as gravi-photon survies. (2). Yes

Comment: The answer by @JohnDoe is completely incorrect. It is ALWAYS consistent to truncate all fermions in a supersymmetric or supergravity theory. This is because the Lagrangian enjous a $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$-symmetry that flips the sign of the fermions.

Answer (score 2):

I think this deserves a proper answer, since the answer by @JohnDoe is incorrect and should be amended. A consistent truncation is, by definition, setting to zero (or to some fixed value) some of the fields of the theory in a way consistent with its equation of motion. In other words,a consistent truncation identically satisfies the equations of motion of the truncated fields. For a supersymmetric theory, it turns out that truncating the fermions is always consistent. This can be explained by noticing that the lagrangian of such theories enjoys a well-defined $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ symmetry on the fermions.

For supergravity theories, one truncates the fermions for example when one is interested in obtaining classical "macroscopic" solutions of these theories, since they cannot contain fermions.